# How do I update row values before taking the mean of the columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that is formed from these lines of code

```
projections = pd.DataFrame({"stock":["A","B","C"],
    "strong":[.39,.30,.06], "moderate":[.17,.15,.14], "weak":[-.05,0,.22]})

projections = projections.set_index("stock")
```

Which looks like this.

```
      strong    moderate    weak
stock           
A      0.39        0.17     -0.05
B      0.30        0.15      0.00
C      0.06         0.14     0.22
```

I want to multiply row "B" by -1 and then take the mean of each column.

Here's what I decided to do.

```
(projections.T * [1,-1,1]).mean(axis=1)
```

But I want a more elegant, generalizable  solution...

---

I want a solution where I could assign any valid list to `mylist`

```
mylist = ["B"]
pd.merge(
    projections.T.loc[:,projections.T.columns.isin(mylist)],
    projections.T.loc[:,~projections.T.columns.isin(mylist)].mul(-1),
    left_index=True, right_index=True
).mean(axis=1)
```

But again more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following to see if it works?

```
(
    projections.T
    .assign(B=lambda x: x.B.mul(-1))
    .mean(1)
)
```

If you have multiple rows to multiply by -1, you can put all those rows to mylist and try the following code.

```
mylist = ["A", "B"]
(
    projections
    .mul([-1 if e in mylist else 1 for e in projections.index], 0)
    .mean(0)
)
```

Comment: It works! I like that solution... Let's say I had had a list of items I wanted to multiply by -1. Is there a compact solution for that?